# What is the best way to get the param values of the model of class A (which is QDialog) in a class B(which is QWidget)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I have a use-case where some model param values of the class A is needed in a method of class B (this widget is added to a layout of the advanced options dialog).

What can be the ways to achieve this ?

One way can obviously be passing the model of advanced options dialog to the widget.

I have my code structure on the lines of below snippet.

I have two files A.ui and B.ui

```
class A(someCustomDialog):

   ui_module = A_ui
   model_class = A_model

   def initSetUp(self):
      super().initSetUp()
      self.my_widget = B()

   def initLayout(self):
      super().initLayout()
      self.ui.layout_1.addWidget(self.my_widget)

class B(someCustomWidget):

    ui_module = B_ui

    def initSetUp(self):
       super().initSetUp()

    def my_method(self):
        # do something which depends on A's model param value
```

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: Do not put the relevant information like the MRE in the comments, instead edit your question and add it there. I recommend you read [ask], [answer] and pass the [tour]

Comment: Your code is not an MRE, read the link so you can understand it.